Determine the rank of a matrix expression
I have posed a question here regarding the determination of the rank of a matrix expression, which has yet to receive a complete answer. Therefore, I want to symbolically define these matrices  for a specific case ( for example: N=n=3, m=p=1) and wrote a program to calculate their rank, hoping this would provide insights for determining the rank of the matrix expression. I have tried this in MATLAB but it was not successful, which I have discussed it further here.
My question is that is it possible to do so in Mathematica?
Edit:
Here the problem is described in detail:
Consider the matrices ${A} \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$, ${B} \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 1}$, and ${C} \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times 3}$ such that the controllability matrix $B_N$ and the observability matrix $O_N$, constructed as follows, are both of rank 3:
$$
\begin{aligned}
B_N &= \left[\begin{array}{lll}
A^2 B & A B & B
\end{array}\right], \\
O_N &= \left[\begin{array}{c}
C \\
C A \\
C A^2
\end{array}\right].
\end{aligned}
$$
Additionally, the matrix $T_N$ is defined as:
$$
T_N = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
C B & 0 & 0 \\
C A B & C B & 0
\end{array}\right].
$$
Write a program that determines the rank of the matrix $M$, which is constructed as follows:
$$
M = \left[B_N - A^3 O_N^{-1} T_N \quad A^3 O_N^{-1}\right].
$$

As is, the question is way to broad and not self-contained. Please narrow it down, i.e., describe the your problem class in more detail and give some example matrices that are somewhat representative of your problem class. Personally, I do not like to have to read through at least two different post to get the idea of what is going on.

Unfortunately, my equations are not displayed correctly

The reason was that they were marked as code, so the SE engine would not recognize it as LaTeX.

It is not guaranteed that the matrix $O_N$ is invertible. For example, A = {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}} and C= {0, 1, 1}. Do you assume $O_N$ is invertible?

we suppose A and C are such that $O_N$ is full rank. I have discussed this at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4946262/1283704

It's relatively straightforward to code this in Mathematica. It seems that OP doesn't have much experience in Mathematica, so let me do a favor. Please read the document carefully by pressing F1 to understand the code.
A = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {3, 3}]


B = Array[Subscript[b, ##] &, {3, 1}]


\[ScriptCapitalC] = Array[Subscript[c, ##] &, {1, 3}]


Please notice I've avoided using C because it's a Protected built-in symbol in Mathematica.
BN = ArrayFlatten[{
     {MatrixPower[A, 2] . B, A . B, B}
    }];

ON = ArrayFlatten[{
     {\[ScriptCapitalC]},
     {\[ScriptCapitalC] . A},
     {\[ScriptCapitalC] . MatrixPower[A, 2]}
    }];

TN = ArrayFlatten[{
     {0, 0, 0},
     {\[ScriptCapitalC] . B, 0, 0},
     {\[ScriptCapitalC] . A . B, \[ScriptCapitalC] . B, 0}
    }];


You may press Ctrl+Enter and Ctrl+, to input matrix. You can also make the matrix pretty by pressing Ctrl+Shift+t to transform the code to TraditionalForm.
Notice ArrayFlatten is necessary because, unlike MATLAB, Mathematica won't automatically transform everything to a matrix.
M = ArrayFlatten[{
     {BN - MatrixPower[A, 3] . Inverse[ON] . TN, MatrixPower[A, 3] . Inverse[ON]}
    }];

M // MatrixRank
(* 3 *)

Finally, you may want to read Possible Issues section of MatrixRank and this post to learn the current limitation of MatrixRank.
